# Xubuntu 20.04 two lock screens after idle

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, xfce, lock-screen, idle

I upgraded from Xubuntu LTS 18.04 to 20.04 yesterday, XFCE version 4.14. When booting the system, I get [this lock screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXJqe.png), which is the one I've always had since 18.04. Everything is fine with that one, I can login to the system without a problem. After leaving the system idle for some time, the screen locks with the same lock screen, but then after putting in my password and pressing enter, a [second lock screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ypKu.jpg) shows up, different from the previous one, and which I suppose is the one coming with 20.04 by default. However, in this second screen I cannot type anything in, I can only click the buttons below the field. If I click switch user, it goes back to the first lock screen, in which I can still type in everything, but again after entering the pass and pressing enter the second screen shows up again and I still can't type anything in, basically leaving me out of the system till reboot.

I want to keep the lock screen feature, not disable it. Is there a way to uninstall either of those lock screens so that I only stay with one of them? Thank you all in advance.

UPDATE: I disabled the "Lock Screen with Screensaver" and "...with System Sleep" on the Screensaver options and, when trying it right away, it works. If a certain amount of time passes though, the same problem of getting locked out happens again.

Comment: The second lock screen (displayed by the screensaver) should be the only one you see after the automatic locking. But if it broken for you, try disabling locking in the screensaver settings. Normally it would completely disable automatic locking, but maybe it'll work in your case?

Comment: XFCE/Xubuntu stopped using the `xscreensaver` due to issues and now uses `xfce4-screensaver` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xfce4-screensaver) so I'd check you don't have both running (I would have expected this switch to be done during upgrade; however if you'd changed your configuration too much, it may not have recognized it & thus you have both active).

Comment: I just looked up the Xubuntu 20.04.1 release notes (https://wiki.xubuntu.org/releases/20.04/release-notes) and the "*Password required twice when switching users*" is noted referring to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1874178 if my prior comment doesn't help.  (the switch to xfce4-screensaver was prior release; 19.10/eoan maybe .. too long ago for me to remember sorry)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you, for whatever reason disabling the "Lock Screen with Screensaver" and "...with System Sleep" options did work. What's weird is that when the screen is locked manually, after idle or after sleep, it goes straight away to the second lock screen without going through the first one and it works as it should.

Comment: @guiverc thank you, I checked and xscreensaver is neither running nor installed anymore, it seems everything is working under xfce4-screensaver. Regarding the release note you mentioned, it is not completely my case since whether I lock it manually, put it to sleep or after idle, the thing does not let me write anything on the second lock screen, so I can't lock back in anymore to the user that got locked. however, weirdly enough the problem was solved by HolyBlackCat's suggestion.